# Magento order confirmation email with shipping estimates

Tags: php, email, magento

I have written some code that depending on the selected shipping method of an order, echos an estimated date on the magento order shipping email. I want to include this in the Magento order confirmation email, however the shipping method title (which I use within an if loop) doesn't exist yet at this stage.

By default, Magento gets the shipping details by calling the followig variable

```
{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}.
```

Is there a way to use this variable within a php file to write some code based on the value of this variable? How would I call the variable within php to do so?

I have tried getting the order shipping method by doing things such as

```
       $this->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription();
```

However This just returns a Call to a member function on a non-object...

I am really lost so any help would be massively appreciated...

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All shipping information are stored in the order object. So you can get them directly from the order model. Basically `{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}` is equal to `$order->getShippingDescription();`. So all you need  to do is to load your order model and then use the code given above to get shipping description.

Have a look at this answer for a descriptive explanation:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30491/14528

Comment: $order->getShippingDescription(); should indeed work, but all i get in return is a call to member function on a non-object :(

Comment: @FrankArcher have you loaded your order model into $order?

Comment: my mistake, it must have been because I was using $this not $object. You are my hero

Comment: Working now, thanks, can you explain what you mean by "loading your order model"

Comment: @FrankArcher you're welcome! :) In Magento you can load different models anywhere in your application using their IDs, SKU, ... ; For example you can load your orders model using their increment ID: e.g. $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000...'); or their entity ID: Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(999..) or .. !! This helps you to manipulate data easily although you should know where/how to use them bcs generally they are heavy stuff! This blog has great posts on Magento: http://inchoo.net/category/magento/